# WinForms ScrollableControl's scrollbars capture mouse wheel?

Tags: c#, winforms, mousewheel

I have a custom ZoomBox control based on ScrollableControl which controls its scrollbars through AutoscrollMinSize property. 
I would like to be able to handle WM_MOUSEWHEEL events to adjust control's Zoom. 
I made necessary steps to make sure that the control receives the mouse events even when it is not in focus, by filtering them on the parent form.

It seems though that the events only reach the OnMouseWheel method if the control does not have its scrollbars active. If it does, it appears that the mousewheel events are being redirected to the scrollbars which handle them (by scrolling).

I would like the scrollbars to be there but only be controlled in a "traditional way", i.e. by dragging the slider or clicking on arrows etc. and handle the wheel myself. Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Inherit from the `ScrollableControl` in question and override `OnMouseWheel()`. In that method **don't** call `base.OnMouseWheel()`.

As far as I can tell there's no other way to stop ScrollableControl from scrolling if the scroll bars are present.

A side effect is that you will no longer get MouseWheel events. Fixing that is another question. Conceptually you want to call base.base.OnMouseWheel().